# how can I sort by one row

Tags: r, sorting

maybe it is a very naive question but I could not figure it out

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(nm1 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("gete", 
"heyet", "heyt", "jeur"), class = "factor"), nm2 = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("gei", "gsfst", "hde", "hsge"), class = "factor"), 
    a1 = c(3L, 1L, 1032L, 617L), a2 = c(4L, 1L, 540L, 663L), 
    h3 = c(5L, 5L, 1411L, 1217L), y1 = c(1L, 1L, 1764L, 972L), 
    u1 = c(3L, 1L, 913L, 396L), i1 = c(0L, 1L, 142L, 156L), t1 = c(1L, 
    3L, 811L, 811L), i9 = c(0L, 1L, 653L, 1010L)), .Names = c("nm1", 
"nm2", "a1", "a2", "h3", "y1", "u1", "i1", "t1", "i9"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I want to sort everything based on one row (row number 3)

If I do this

```
t(apply(df[,-(1:2)], 1, sort))
```

it will sort everything

how can I sort them by one row?

the solution does not work when the column names are odd like an example below

```
df2<- structure(list(name1 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("KILA", 
"KKIK"), class = "factor"), name2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("BIN", 
"BINA"), class = "factor"), X4932NMU = c(1033L, 846L), X4931NMU = c(1035L, 
847L), X4928NMU = c(1053L, 143L), X4927NMU = c(13255L, 1517L), 
    X4926NMU = c(1332L, 194L), X4097NMU = c(1351L, 231L), X2572NMU = c(13542L, 
    253L), X2571NMU = c(1441L, 272L), X5222NMU = c(14691L, 322L
    ), X4213NMU = c(1738L, 322L), X2638NMU = c(1742L, 338L)), .Names = c("name1", 
"name2", "X4932NMU", "X4931NMU", "X4928NMU", "X4927NMU", "X4926NMU", 
"X4097NMU", "X2572NMU", "X2571NMU", "X5222NMU", "X4213NMU", "X2638NMU"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

for example

```
ix <- 1:2 
o <- order(df2[1, -ix]) 
cbind(df2[ix], df2[-ix][o])
```

or

```
newdata <- df2[, c(1:2, order(df2[1, 3:ncol(df2) ]) + 2)]
```

Comment: `df[,order(df[3,])]` gives the sort of row three (`order(df[,3])`) and rearranges the columns accordingly.

Comment: @Edward Carney it does not, please try it on the example data above df[,order(df[3,])]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `o`, the indexes which sort row 3 except for columns 1 and 2.  Then apply to that `df` except for columns 1 and 2 and prepend columns 1 and 2.

```
ix <- 1:2
o <- order(df[3, -ix])
cbind(df[ix], df[-ix][o])
```

giving:

```
    nm1   nm2  i1  a2   i9  t1  u1   a1   h3   y1
1  heyt   hde   0   4    0   1   3    3    5    1
2  jeur  hsge   1   1    1   3   1    1    5    1
3 heyet gsfst 142 540  653 811 913 1032 1411 1764
4  gete   gei 156 663 1010 811 396  617 1217  972
```

### Note

In response to the comment:

```
names(df)[3:5] <- c("0047NMU", "125NMU", "457NMU")
o <- order(df[3, -ix])
cbind(df[ix], df[-ix][, o])
```

giving:

```
    nm1   nm2  i1 125NMU   i9  t1  u1 0047NMU 457NMU   y1
1  heyt   hde   0      4    0   1   3       3      5    1
2  jeur  hsge   1      1    1   3   1       1      5    1
3 heyet gsfst 142    540  653 811 913    1032   1411 1764
4  gete   gei 156    663 1010 811 396     617   1217  972
```

### Note 2

Using `df2` and row 1 for ordering we get this:

```
ix <- 1:2; o <- order(df2[1, -ix]); cbind(df2[ix], df2[-ix][o])
```

giving:

```
  name1 name2 X4932NMU X4931NMU X4928NMU X4926NMU X4097NMU X2571NMU X4213NMU
1  KKIK   BIN     1033     1035     1053     1332     1351     1441     1738
2  KILA  BINA      846      847      143      194      231      272      322
  X2638NMU X4927NMU X2572NMU X5222NMU
1     1742    13255    13542    14691
2      338     1517      253      322
```

Comment: the solution does not work when the column names are odd, please look at above , I posted an example

Comment: please use my example. I do the same command as you wrote but it does not. I order based on the first row and there are only two rows, please just use this `ix <- 1:2
o <- order(df2[1, -ix])
cbind(df2[ix], df2[-ix][o])`

Comment: I see, my data shows to be `chr` while the data i posted is ìnt` do you know how to convert the chr to int?

Comment: `df3 <- df2; df3[-ix] <- lapply(df3[-ix], as.integer)`

Comment: I liked and accepted your answer. it would be nice if you could show how to order it descending too :-) thanks again

Comment: For descending, negate `df[3, -ix]` and calculate the order of that: `o <- order(-df[3, -ix])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
newdata <- df[, c(1:2, order(df[3, 3:ncol(df) ]) + 2)]
```

result:

```
> newdata
    nm1   nm2  i1  a2   i9  t1  u1   a1   h3   y1
1  heyt   hde   0   4    0   1   3    3    5    1
2  jeur  hsge   1   1    1   3   1    1    5    1
3 heyet gsfst 142 540  653 811 913 1032 1411 1764
4  gete   gei 156 663 1010 811 396  617 1217  972
```

Explanation:

We sort based on columns 3 to 10 and row 3

```
order(df[3, 3:ncol(df) ])
```

This produces the desired indexes

```
[1] 6 2 8 7 5 1 3 4
```

Following, we need to add "2" to the indexes to make them compatible with the original data frame and exclude the columns corresponding to the names.

```
order(df[3, 3:ncol(df) ]) + 2
[1]  8  4 10  9  7  3  5  6
```

Comment: use my second data example and you see that it does not work